# Parent not defined when testing a directive element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have an angularjs directive that just assigns the height of the element to equal height of its second parent (something like `element.height = element.parent().parent().height`) in the link function.

However, when I create and try to compile the directive element in my unit test against an isolated scope, I get `element.parent().parent().height` is not a function. I suppose the parent is somehow undefined when compiling.

How can it be resolved using the same or different approach? Thanks.

Comment: This `element.parent().parent().height` [code smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell). Using such approach you force your child directive to dependent on the markup and structure of parent elements, which makes not reusable and easily testable,as we can see from your question.

Comment: When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

You could mock the `element.parent().parent().height` call with a fake height response and check that your element's height was set to that.

What I'd do is implement a function and call the function as part of the "Arrange" step of your unit test.

```
mockGetHeightFromParent = function (mockHeight) {
    spyOn(element, 'parent').and.returnValue({
        parent: function () {
            return mockHeight;
        }
    )};
}

it("should use height of the parent's parent", function () {
    // Arrange
    mockGetHeightFromParent(1337);

    // Act
    // Instantiate directive

    // Assert
    expect(element.height).toEqual(1337);
}
```